# Is this answer rude, or just not an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-post-review

I came across this answer in the first posts queue. I generally don't come across very many rude comments on Stack Overflow, aside from the lmgtfy type responses where an asker hasn't done the required research.

I wasn't sure whether to flag this as rude/abusive or not an answer. I'm sure both flags are relevant. Which is more appropriate?

[image: The post mainly complains that no one answered the original question.]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It simply doesn't matter which flag you use for answers like this. Use whichever flag type speaks to you.

You already recognized that it is inappropriate for SO and needs to be brought to moderator attention, and that's the most important thing.

If you think it counts as "rude/abusive", then flag it as such. If not, "not an answer" is fine. Either way, a mod is going to delete it. Worst case, we'll "dispute" your "rude/abusive" flag if we don't think that the poster deserves the penalty associated with these flags, but having a flag "disputed" doesn't count against you in any way.

Answer (score 8):

I would probably flag the above Answer as "not an answer", even though it might be rude, but it certainly does not answer anything. I feel the answer should be a comment if anything, but I would probably flag it as "It's unfriendly or unkind." if it were a comment.

Comment: This conveys no meaningful or useful information, so it would *not* be appropriate as a comment, either.

Comment: Umm.  'might' be rude??  If it was a comment from an experienced SO curator, they would be suspended and, likely, pilloried on 'Contact us', Facepalm, Tattler etc.

Comment: Don't worry, @Martin. We have your pillory reserved. :-)